# How to do list comprehension in Java

Tags: java, list-comprehension

I'm writing a program and I want to shorten the code through list comprehension (like those in Python). However, I faced syntax errors while trying to simplify the code:

I've attempted to troubleshoot this problem multiple times, but all the solutions they proposed are through ArrayLists while I want to complete this task in the form of an integer array (int[]).

```java
boolean[][] seats;
Theater(int row, int col) {
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++) for (int j=0; j<col; j++) seats[i][j] = false;
}

public int[] findSeats(int row) {
    int[] arr = [x for (boolean x : this.seats[row]) if (x == false)];
    return arr;
}
```

I expected the code above to work but the following messages showed up instead:

```java
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
Syntax error on token "]", delete this token
```

Can anyone please help? Much appreciated.

Comment: Your list comprehension should give a `boolean[]`, not `int[]`. Do you want to convert `true` to 1 and `false` to 0 or something? Remember that Java is stricter about types.

Comment: Is `int[] arr = [x ` just a copy and paste problem ?

Comment: @Marged No, OP is trying to use [list comprehensions in python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) in Java...

Comment: Java is not python. Java does not have this language feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language construct of Python is not available in Java. I assume you are finding vacant seats in a row? The closest I thought will be something like this

```
public int[] findSeats(int row) {

        final int[] avSeats = new int[seats[row].length];
        IntStream.range(0, seats[row].length).filter(seatNo -> !seats[row][seatNo]).forEach(seatNo -> avSeats[seatNo] = 1);
        return avSeats;

    }
```